# How come I can't print the name in my structure?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, dynamic-arrays

I am reading in a file of data with names IDs and grades and I am storing the info in a struc and using a pointer array to store struc addresss. After I am done I am dynamically allocating it to an array and then I want to print the names in all the structs yet nothing prints and there is no error message. How do I print the names in each of the structs in the new dynamic array?

Here is my code below

```
ifstream inFile;
Student *students[100];

string netID, studentName;
double grade1, grade2, grade3;

inFile.open("Asg3Grades.txt"); //opens the file

int counter = 0;

while(inFile.eof()){
    inFile >> netID >> studentName >> grade1 >> grade2 >> grade3;

    double average = (grade1+grade2+grade3)/3;

    students[counter]->ID=netID;
    students[counter]->name=studentName;
    students[counter]->grade=average;

    counter++;
}

inFile.close(); //closes the file

Student *dynamicStudents = nullptr;
dynamicStudents = new Student[counter];

for (int i=0; i<counter; i++) {
    dynamicStudents[i] = *(students[i]);
}

for (int i=0; i<counter; i++) {
    cout << dynamicStudents[i].name << endl;
}

return 0;
```

Comment: `Student *students[100];` is an array of 100 pointers. Where do those pointers point to? You don't allocate any memory for actual `Student` objects

Comment: `while(inFile.eof())` is wrong.  And `Student* students[100];` should be `Student students[100];` (`Student` objects instead of `Student*` pointers), but if you change it to `std::vector<Student> students;` then you can get rid of `dynamicStudents` and `counter` altogether as `vector` is already a dynamic array.

Comment: For useful reference, declarations like `Student *students[100];` are read from right to left: Array, of 100 elements, named students, comprised of pointers of Student type.

Comment: @Tzalumen actually, they are better read [in a spiral instead](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something more like this:

```
ifstream inFile;

Student students[100];
int counter = 0;

string line, netID, studentName;
double grade1, grade2, grade3;

inFile.open("Asg3Grades.txt"); //opens the file

while (getline(inFile, line)) {

    istringstream iss(line);

    if (iss >> netID >> studentName >> grade1 >> grade2 >> grade3) {

        double average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3;

        students[counter].ID = netID;
        students[counter].name = studentName;
        students[counter].grade = average;

        if (++counter == 100) break;
    }
}

inFile.close(); //closes the file

Student *dynamicStudents = new Student[counter];

for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    dynamicStudents[i] = students[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    cout << dynamicStudents[i].name << endl;
}

delete[] dynamicStudents;
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/7N6wRm)

Though, you don't really need the fixed array at all:

```
ifstream inFile;

Student* students = nullptr;
int counter = 0, capacity = 0;

string line, netID, studentName;
double grade1, grade2, grade3;

inFile.open("Asg3Grades.txt"); //opens the file

while (getline(inFile, line)) {

    istringstream iss(line);

    if (iss >> netID >> studentName >> grade1 >> grade2 >> grade3) {

        double average = (grade1+grade2+grade3)/3;

        if (counter == capacity)
        {
            Student *temp = new Student[capacity + 100];
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
                temp[i] = students[i];
            delete[] students;
            students = temp;
            capacity += 100;
        }

        students[counter].ID = netID;
        students[counter].name = studentName;
        students[counter].grade = average;

        ++counter;
    }
}

inFile.close(); //closes the file

for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i) {
    cout << students[i].name << endl;
}

delete[] students;
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/CkGRSA)

Which can be simplified further by using `std::vector` instead of `new[]`:

```
ifstream inFile;
vector<Student> students;

string line, netID, studentName;
double grade1, grade2, grade3;

inFile.open("Asg3Grades.txt"); //opens the file

while (getline(inFile, line)) {

    istringstream iss(line);

    if (iss >> netID >> studentName >> grade1 >> grade2 >> grade3) {

        double average = (grade1+grade2+grade3)/3;

        Student student;
        student.ID = netID;
        student.name = studentName;
        student.grade = average;

        students.push_back(student);
    }
}

inFile.close(); //closes the file

for (size_t i = 0; i < student.size(); ++i) {
    cout << students[i].name << endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/h4j43b)

Comment: But I don't know how many students are in the file just that it wont go over 100 but it can be less

Comment: @Unknownzdx "*I don't know how many students are in the file*" - It is exactly for that reason that you should use `vector`, it grows dynamically as needed.  If you know the number will never exceed 100, you can `reserve()` the `vector` before filling it to reduce memory reallocations.  But either way, `getline()` will stop reading when it reaches the end of the file, assuming each student is on its own line in the file.

Comment: But for this I can't use vectors, so with the first example, how would you make it so there can be less then 100 students as well?

Comment: @Unknownzdx The 1st example I gave already does exactly that. Like I said, the `getline()` loop will stop automatically when it reaches the end of the file, leaving the `counter` less than 100. Did you even try it?

Comment: No my bad, I was looking at the break part of the code and misunderstood.

Comment: @Unknownzdx I added that `break` as a safety catch, since you did not state initially how many students were in the file.  If the file had more than 100 students, you would have exceeded the capacity of the static array and corrupted surrounding memory. But if you know the count will never exceed the size of the static array, you can take out that safety.  Otherwise, get rid of the static array completely and just use the dynamic array by itself, growing it when needed.

Comment: I tried the code you used, but it still doesn't print anything

Comment: @Unknownzdx [works fine for me](https://ideone.com/7N6wRm), as does [this one, too](https://ideone.com/CkGRSA), and [this one, too](https://ideone.com/h4j43b).

Comment: Thank you, it was a file problem your code helps so much